# Prevent the cursor from moving to the top of the file

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement, cursor-motions

I started using [Seeing is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing)
 and updated my [vimrc](https://github.com/ogirginc/dotfiles/blob/master/vimrc#L297-L298):

```
nmap <leader>s A # => <Esc>:%.!seeing_is_believing --timeout 12 --line-length 500 --number-of-captures 300 --alignment-strategy chunk --xmpfilter-style<CR>
```

However, after I run the command, my cursor moves to the top of the file.

Is there a way to keep my cursor in the original line & column that I ran the command?

Comment: I'm not sure what `seeing_is_believing` is, but you could always mark your position at the beginning of the command with `ma` and then return to that position with `a.

Answer (score 1):

In theory:

You could end your map with `''` to jump back to the first non blank column on the line where you were:

```
nmap <leader>s A # => <Esc>:%.!seeing_is_believing --timeout 12 --line-length 500 --number-of-captures 300 --alignment-strategy chunk --xmpfilter-style<CR>''
```

Or you could use ``` `` ``` to jump back to the exact column on the line where you were:

```
nmap <leader>s A # => <Esc>:%.!seeing_is_believing --timeout 12 --line-length 500 --number-of-captures 300 --alignment-strategy chunk --xmpfilter-style<CR>``
```

Or you could just hit `<CTRL-o`> (`:h CTRL-o`) to go to older cursor position on the jump list.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Isrdg but these solutions didn't work for me. I seem to get `E20: Mark not set` warning. 

Also, when I use `u`, there seems to be a more than 1 change. This might be preventing Vim from understanding my  **real** last used line. Any suggestions? :/

Comment: No idea, but just let me know if you want me to delete the answer. (:
In the meantime, two things: 1) you could try to start your map by setting a mark as @Tumbler41 said, and 2) note the "A" in the beginning of the map, isn't it already changing the cursor position (but not "jumping", though not setting the ``` `` ``` mark)? And aparantly the Vim integration was done by the author, you could create an issue on the repository (and come back here with the solution o/).

Answer (score 0):

Vim has a couple of functions to help with this, namely `winsaveview()` and `winrestview()`. Here's an example of how you might use them:

```
fun! Stayput(cmd)
    let v = winsaveview()
    exec a:cmd
    call winrestview(v)
endfun
nno <leader>s mmA # => <Esc>`m:silent call Stayput('%!seeing_is_believing ...')<CR>
```

So save your view, do some stuff, then restore your view, including cursor and scroll positions, to exactly
how it was before. I've wrapped it up in a function for convenience.

A few other notes:

- consider using `:nnoremap` rather than `:nmap`;
- I've used a mark in the mapping to return the cursor to where it
  was before the comment was appended;
- I've used `:silent` to prevent editing messages appearing
  in the last line of the screen; and
- I'm not sure what the `.` in `%.!` is meant to be doing.

More info. at `:help winsaveview()`.